# Where is implemented/configured/declared that Identity UI /Account/Manage pages require authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've scaffolded all Identity UI pages to my ASP.NET Core (razor pages) project. The /Account/Manage pages should be restricted to authorized users, which is work perfectly, however I can not find where this restriction is implemented/configured/declared.

I mean no traces of `[Authorize]` attribute. I've also took a look into the original sources both 5.0.12 and 6.0.0 and the [original UI source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.12/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml.cs) also do not have such attribute

**Question**

Where is this authorization requirement (which is working, and are in effect) implemented, coded/declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't followed the whole call stack from startup code:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

but in IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.12/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions.cs

there is the code:

```
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder(IdentityUIDefaultAreaName, "/Account/Manage");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage(IdentityUIDefaultAreaName, "/Account/Logout");
```

which uses: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0bc3c376f0cd14335e8b3afca69596acabeb1f80/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/DependencyInjection/PageConventionCollectionExtensions.cs#L407

that adds the attributes dynamically:

```
   public static PageConventionCollection AuthorizeAreaFolder(
        this PageConventionCollection conventions,
        string areaName,
        string folderPath,
        string policy)
    {
        if (conventions == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conventions));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Resources.ArgumentCannotBeNullOrEmpty, nameof(areaName));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Resources.ArgumentCannotBeNullOrEmpty, nameof(folderPath));
        }

        conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention(areaName, folderPath, model =>
        {
            if (conventions.MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting)
            {
                model.EndpointMetadata.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute(policy));
            }
            else
            {
                model.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }
        });
        return conventions;
    }
```

Comment: cool, both your approach and the result, thx